# Cloning a Mercurial repository without .hg

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How can I clone a Mercurial repository without the `.hg` folder to save time (the project is big)? I only need the tip files.

Comment: How are you thinking that this would save time? Would any changes be done to the non-repo copy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `.hg` directory is what stores your complete repository information. That is, information about all your files and their revisions tracked by the repository. As for storage, it usually is pretty efficient since it is compressed using binary differerencing.

When you clone a repository, the only thing that is cloned is the .hg directory. The working copy you will get after the clone is retrieved from that `.hg`.

If all you want to store is the repository information (say on a server), you can remove the working copy with `hg update null`.

If you want to create a clone of your repository without the revision information, you can use the `hg archive` command (see reference below). Be aware that this copy is just a "working copy" (to use some common svn terminology). You can't commit, nor do any other mercurial operation with it.

> hg archive [OPTION]... DEST
>
> create unversioned archive of a
>   repository revision
>
> ```
> By default, the revision used is the parent of the working
> directory; use "-r" to specify a different revision.
>
> To specify the type of archive to create, use "-t". Valid
> types are:
>
> "files" (default): a directory full of files
> "tar": tar archive, uncompressed
> "tbz2": tar archive, compressed using bzip2
> "tgz": tar archive, compressed using gzip
> "uzip": zip archive, uncompressed
> "zip": zip archive, compressed using deflate
>
> The exact name of the destination archive or directory is given
> using a format string; see "hg help export" for details.
>
> Each member added to an archive file has a directory prefix
> prepended. Use "-p" to specify a format string for the prefix.
> The default is the basename of the archive, with suffixes removed.
> ```
>
> options:
>
> ```
> --no-decode  do not pass files through decoders  -p --prefix
> ```
>
> directory prefix for files in archive 
>   -r --rev        revision to distribute  -t --type       type of distribution to create  -I --include    include
>   names matching the given patterns  -X
>   --exclude    exclude names matching the given patterns

Comment: As a clarification, the destination may contain formatted information provided by the format string, but a plain old path will do too.  The formatting lets you encode info about the repo in the path to which you would be archiving.